# Pass number string to setcounter

Tags: convert, currfile

Here's my current MWE: (Note, you must save the file as lec-05.tex)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{substr}

\def\fulllecnum{
  \BehindSubString{lec-}{\scantokens\expandafter{\currfilebase\noexpand}}
}
\newcommand\lecnum{
  \IfBehindSubStringEmpty{lec-0}{\scantokens\expandafter{\currfilebase\noexpand}}{
    \BehindSubString{lec-}{\scantokens\expandafter{\currfilebase\noexpand}}
  }{
    \BehindSubString{lec-0}{\scantokens\expandafter{\currfilebase\noexpand}}
  }
}

\setcounter{section}{\lecnum}

\begin{document}
  \section{HI}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.17 \setcounter{section}{\lecnum}
                                  
?
```

How can I convert `\lecnum` to an integer and then pass it to `\setcounter{section}{}`?

Comment: You need to process and store the results of [`xstring`](//ctan.org/pkg/xstring) macros *first*, before you can pass that to some other function; fundamentally the `xstring` extractions aren't expandable.

Comment: Could you explain what it means to be expandable?

Comment: Perhaps start here: [Why isn't everything expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35039/5764). For [`xstring`](//ctan.org/pkg/xstring), use the optional final argument to store the result of some string test/extraction. Then you can use that result somewhere else.

Comment: you can split the argument using expansion but why split? it would seem more natural and easier to start from the number. \newcommand\lec[1]{\setcounter{section}{#1}\input{lec-#1}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David Carlisle who pointed this out.

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\@lecnum{}
\newcommand\lec[1]{%
  \ifnum #1<10 %
    \def\@lecnum{0#1}%
  \else
    \def\@lecnum{#1}%
  \fi
%
  \setcounter{section}{#1}%
  \renewcommand\thesubsection{#1.\arabic{subsection}}%
%
  \input{lectures/lec-\@lecnum.tex}%
}
\makeatother
```

I have files in the `lectures` folder named `lec-01.tex`, `lec-02.tex`, `...`. Then, I can just call this command like `\lec{1}` and it sets the section number to `1` and inputs the `lectures/lec-01.tex` file.

I was doing it the complicated way, first getting the lecture number from performing regex on the file name, then trying to convert that string to a number to set the section number.

Comment: TeX language is not “free-form”. Watch out for spaces, endlines and blank lines in definitions.