# How to expand a macro in \setcounter?

Tags: setcounter

I am using exam class to typeset an exam. As MWE, my exam has an MCQ section and Short answer sections.

In the grade table, I want the MCQ section to display as one row of total marks (instead of 20-30 boxes of 1 point), and the Short section to be by question. Since there is no pre-defined command, I thought to write my own table generator:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{qnitr}
\setcounter{qnitr}{\firstqinrange{short}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Qns & Points & Score \\\hline
    MCQ & \pointsinrange{mcq} & \\\hline
    \whiledo{ \not \( \theqnitr > \lastqinrange{short} \) }{%
        \ifthenelse{ \not \( \theqnitr > \lastqinrange{short} \) }{%
            \theqnitr & \pointsofquestion{\theqnitr} & \\ \hline
        }{blah}
        \stepcounter{qnitr}
    }
    Total: & \numpoints & \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{questions}
    \section{MCQ Section}
    \begingradingrange{mcq}
        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 1

        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 2

        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 3
    \endgradingrange{mcq}

    \section{Short Answer Section}
    \begingradingrange{short}
        \question
        This question has 3 parts.
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2]
                Part 1.
            \part[2]
                Part 2.
            \part[3]
                Part 3
        \end{parts}

        \question
        This question has 2 parts.
            \begin{parts}
            \part[5]
                Part 1.
            \part[4]
                Part 2.
        \end{parts}
    \endgradingrange{short}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is a table like this:

[image]

However, `\setcounter{qnitr}{\firstqinrange{short}}` is giving me an error.

I've spent hours trying to look up expanding macros for use in `\setcounter` but I can't seem to find a solution. I learned that `\setcounter` is fragile and requires expansion to a number. But I've tried various combinations of `\noexpand`, `\protect`, `\value` and due to my lack of knowledge and understanding of LaTeX evaluation, I am just randomly trying.

I looked into the `exam.cls` to find clues on how the table is generated and found codes like

```
\edef\tbl@firstq{\csname range@\tbl@range @firstq\endcsname}%
\edef\tbl@lastq{\csname range@\tbl@range @lastq\endcsname}%
\let\first@pq@index=\tbl@firstq
\let\last@pq@index=\tbl@lastq

...

\setcounter{num@cols}{\tbl@lastq}%
\addtocounter{num@cols}{-\tbl@firstq}%
```

How come the exam class is able to set a counter to a command but when I try to do it, it keeps failing?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to expand a macro inside of `\setcounter`'s second argument, but the macro you're using there has to be expandable. I'd guess that `\firstqinrange` isn't fully expandable, and hence you're getting these problems.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the expansion and evaluation mode. Even after spending few hours researching the on this. I'm guessing that `\firstqinrange` needs to be evaluated, but `\setcounter` is only doing expansion? In this case how can I evaluate it to a number, then use it in `\setcounter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking the `exam.cls` file. The actual number of question range generated using `\firstqinrange` and `\lastqinrange` can be called by these two marcos `\range@short@firstq`,`\range@short@lastq`

So the code should be edited as follow:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}


\begin{document}

\newcounter{fqr}
\newcounter{lqr}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{fqr}{\range@short@firstq}
\setcounter{lqr}{\range@short@lastq}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Qns & Points & Score \\\hline
    MCQ & \pointsinrange{mcq} & \\\hline
    \whiledo{ \not \( \thefqr > \thelqr \) }{%
        \ifthenelse{
        \not \( \thefqr > \thelqr \) }{%
            \thefqr & \pointsofquestion{\thefqr} & \\ \hline%
        }{blah}%
        \stepcounter{fqr}%
    }
    Total: & \numpoints & \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{questions}
    \section{MCQ Section}
    \begingradingrange{mcq}
        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 1

        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 2

        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 3
    \endgradingrange{mcq}

    \section{Short Answer Section}
    \begingradingrange{short}
        \question
        This question has 3 parts.
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2]
                Part 1.
            \part[2]
                Part 2.
            \part[3]
                Part 3
        \end{parts}

        \question
        This question has 2 parts.
            \begin{parts}
            \part[5]
                Part 1.
            \part[4]
                Part 2.
        \end{parts}
    \endgradingrange{short}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Edit: I will try my best to ask your question. If anything mentioned here aren't right. Please correct me.  The problem come from the `\def` command in `\firstqinrange` and `\lastqinrange` definition. If you take a look the definition of these two commands in `exam.cls` file. For example, for `\firstqinrange`:

```
\newcommand{\firstqinrange}[1]{%
  \def\tbl@range{#1}% define a macro using #1, e.g. If this is the short range, #1=short.
  \@ifundefined{range@\tbl@range @firstq}% use previous macro in here to judge if command \range@short@firstq has not been defined.
  {\bad@range}% If true, return a error.
  {\csname range@#1@firstq\endcsname}% If false, return \range@short@firstq.
}% firstqinrange
```

In this definition, the command `\def` is not expandable. Why? You could take a look this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable). So to better illustrate this, we could patch the command `\firstqinrange` and `\lastqinrange` to eliminate the `\def` commands using package `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\firstqinrange}{\def\tbl@range{#1}\@ifundefined{range@\tbl@range @firstq}}{\@ifundefined{range@#1@firstq}}{}{}

%% get rid of `\def\tbl@range{#1}` and using `range@#1@firstq` as value testing the define state.

\patchcmd{\lastqinrange}{\def\tbl@range{#1}\@ifundefined{range@\tbl@range @lastq}}{\@ifundefined{range@#1@lastq}}{}{}

%% get rid of `\def\tbl@range{#1}` and using `range@#1@lastq` as value testing the define state.
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newcounter{fqr}
\newcounter{lqr}
\setcounter{fqr}{\firstqinrange{short}}%%use `\firstqinrange{short}` to set the counter
\setcounter{lqr}{\lastqinrange{short}}%%use `\firstqinrange{short}` to set the counter

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Qns & Points & Score \\\hline
    MCQ & \pointsinrange{mcq} & \\\hline
    \whiledo{ \not \( \thefqr > \thelqr \) }{%
        \ifthenelse{
        \not \( \thefqr > \thelqr \) }{%
            \thefqr & \pointsofquestion{\thefqr} & \\ \hline%
        }{blah}%
        \stepcounter{fqr}%
    }
    Total: & \numpoints & \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{questions}
    \section{MCQ Section}
    \begingradingrange{mcq}
        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 1

        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 2

        \question[2]
        MCQ Question 3
    \endgradingrange{mcq}

    \section{Short Answer Section}
    \begingradingrange{short}
        \question
        This question has 3 parts.
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2]
                Part 1.
            \part[2]
                Part 2.
            \part[3]
                Part 3
        \end{parts}

        \question
        This question has 2 parts.
            \begin{parts}
            \part[5]
                Part 1.
            \part[4]
                Part 2.
        \end{parts}
    \endgradingrange{short}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Right now the code is using `\setcounter{fqr}{\firstqinrange{short}}` to set the counter and It is successfully compiled without errors.

Comment: I guess that works. I tried doing that in the document but it fails because the macro name has a `@`. I read that macros uses such special characters are not meant to be used externally. Which is the purpose of `\firstqinrange`. So while this "hack" immediately solves my problem, I would still like to learn if there is a less "hackish" solution?

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it solves my problem. But I would still like to learn why `\setcounter{range@short@firstq}` works but `\setcounter{\firstqinrange{short}}` fails.

Comment: @welcomb I made some additional explanations for your question. See the new edits in the answer.